# AWS .NET SDK - Get list of EC2 instances for beanstalk app

Tags: .net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

Is there a way to get a list of EC2 instances created by a given Beanstalk application? I am using the C# AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Using the AWSSDK.ElasticBeanstalk NuGet package you can use the `DescribeEnvironmentResources` API to get the ID of the all of the resources created for the environment including the ECS instance ids.

```
using var ebClient = new AmazonElasticBeanstalkClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

var environmentResources = (await ebClient.DescribeEnvironmentResourcesAsync(new DescribeEnvironmentResourcesRequest
{
    EnvironmentName = environmentName
})).EnvironmentResources;

foreach(var instance in environmentResources.Instances)
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance.Id);
}
```